# Plot two line graphs in same figure with different colours and x and y axis ranges are fixed

Tags: matplotlib, plot, seaborn, data-visualization, linegraph

I have two lists like this

```
l1= [2, 8, 5, 19, 15, 23]
l2= [3, 5, 8, 11, 14, 50]
```

Now I want to plot line graph this where the Y axis will be having range 0 to 50 and X axis will be having range from 0 to 50. both l1 and l2 lines will be having different colour. How to do this using matplotlib or seaborn ?

Comment: what's the range of the X-axis? Your question is not clear.

Comment: @Nk03 edited. both 0 to 50

Comment: And these points corresponds to `x = [0,10,20,30,40,50]` ?

Comment: @Nk03 Yes, you are right

Answer (score 2):

- Load the list into `pandas` dataframe.
- Restructure the dataframe
- Plot via seaborn.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

l1= [2, 8, 5, 19, 15, 23]
l2= [3, 5, 8, 11, 14, 50]

df = pd.DataFrame({'l1': l1, 'l2': l2}).stack().reset_index(name='val').assign(level_0 = lambda x: x.level_0 * 10)
sns.set_style('whitegrid')
fg = sns.lineplot(x="level_0", y = "val" , hue="level_1", data=df,  ci=None, palette='Set1')

plt.savefig('test5.png')
```

#### OUTPUT:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to use `matplotlib.pyplot` directly.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
l1= [2, 8, 5, 19, 15, 23]
l2= [3, 5, 8, 11, 14, 50]

plt.ylim((0, 50))  # set Y axis range to 0..50
plt.xlim((0, 50))  # set X axis range to 0..50
plt.plot(l1, color='red')  # plot l1
plt.plot(l2, color='blue') # plot l2
plt.show()
```

See [matplotlib.pyplot.plot()](https://matplotlib.org/2.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) for further styling options.